# 19.10: Black screen & no GRUB when connecting DisplayPort to GTX970

Tags: grub2, nvidia, displayport

The PC is connected via **DisplayPort** cable to the monitor. When I power on the PC, I can see the BIOS messages. When it comes to displaying the GRUB menu, the screen turns black and nothing happens.

Switching to DVI cable afterwards does not help (screen stays black).
Pressing the power button switches off the PC instantly.
Waiting for GRUB timeout -> nothing happens (Linux is not booting)

This tells me, GRUB isn't starting at all.

However, if I connect the DVI cable before switching the power on, boot into Linux and then connect the DisplayPort cable, it works fine. The display is recognized automatically. So I guess there is nothing wrong with the hardware but maybe some kind of driver problem with GRUB.

Maybe it is related to this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1853735

Not sure, how to debug this. Could not find any pre boot GRUB logfiles.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    Mainboard: Asus P7P55D-E PRO
    Graphics card: NVIDIA GTX970
    Driver: nvidia-driver-390 390.120-0ubuntu2
    Distro: Kubuntu 19.10
```

Comment: Can you please check if it works with Windows? Perhaps it is necessary to activate Display Port

Comment: Its working with both Linux and Windows, if I connect the monitor after grub has loaded. Screen stays black until the OS has started, though.

Comment: I have slightly similar issue with some HDMI monitors - the monitor goes power saving and never wakes up. The problem started to appear with Ubuntu 18. Previous versions and and all Windows versions are ok with these monitors. The only solution for me is to press Fn-F7 to switch to one monitor and again to two monitors.